# How to define the integral over boundary in R^n(n>3)

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am a math undergraduate. While learning the theory of PDEs, I find many textbooks(evans' for instance) just cite formula and conclusions related to the integral of a function with n variables over the boundary of a open set U in R^n, without proof or explaining. But when I Studied basic analysis, we only       learned how to deal with the R^3 case(integral over surface in R^3) and I Don't know what it means when it comes to n>3. I just want to know which or what kind of textbooks  will discuss this kind of integral issues, such as exact definition and how to calculate or understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Very generally, differential forms are things which are integrated over, so for a deep perspective, you might look at differential geometry or manifolds textbooks. You also have the option of going the analysis/measure theory route, but if you want more calculation, physics-oriented treatments of differential forms might be best imo!